# appending date as suffix in (dd/mm/yyyyy) format to file name in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

I have to append date format in my file name.
If i give date format in dd/mm/yyyy it throws an error.

while it works in all other format - ex: dd-mm-yyyyy or ddmmyyyy

Example-

- myfile_01/12/2017 throws an error. Because it interprates '/' as a path.

  - myfile_01-12-2017 works fine.

Comment: The format dd/mm/yyyy contains special character '/' i.e. (forward slash) which is not supported by javascript.

Comment: show us the code

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and take the tour to see what and how to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, that's because the '/' character in most file-systems is used to indicate a new file directory. What effectively happens is that the date is seen as another folder, with a sub-directory of the month, with a further-subdirectory of the year.

Comment: Yes, Exactly this is the problem. But how can i resolve it?

Comment: Even if there were a way to get around this, it's such bad practice I'd strongly advise you use another format, e.g hyphenated. Sorry I guess this isn't the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the library Moment.js to get desired format. It wouldn't have worked because of some formatting errors.

Refer to the below example code that prints the date in dd/mm/yyyy format.

```
function DateFormat(mydate)
{

var day = mydate.getDate().toString(); //converting it to string
day = day.length > 1 ? day : '0' + day; //condition to check values

var month = (1 + mydate.getMonth()).toString(); //converting it to string
month = month.length > 1 ? month : '0' + month; //condition to check values

var year = mydate.getFullYear(); 



return day + '/' + month + '/' + year; //here is the format dd/mm/yyyy
}
```

Hope this helps!